# SQL Alchemy Join Multiple Columns from same table

Tags: python, sql, join, sqlalchemy

```
class Match(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'matches'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(Date, nullable=False)
    time = Column(Time, nullable=True)
    league_id = Column(ForeignKey('leagues.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    league = relationship('League', backref='matches')
    type = Column(enums.matches_types)
    home_team_id = Column(ForeignKey('teams.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    home_team = relationship('Team', foreign_keys=[home_team_id], backref='home_matches')
    away_team_id = Column(ForeignKey('teams.id'), nullable=False, index=True)


class Team(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'teams'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    country_id = Column(ForeignKey('countries.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    country = relationship('Country', backref='teams')
```

I need to write a query that joins columns and teams tables displaying information of the teams information for both local and away team.

```
Session.query(Match.date, Match.home_team.name, Match_away_team.name).joins(Team)
```

This returns `Can't determine join between 'matches' and 'teams'; tables have more than one foreign key constraint relationship between them. Please specify the 'onclause' of this join explicitly`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, the reason your code doesn't work is because SQLAlchemy doesn't know whether you want to join to `Team` via `home_team` or `away_team`, so you'll have to tell it. In addition, you'll need to join to `Team` twice, which further complicates things.

This can be done more easily by using [`joinedload`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.joinedload):

```
matches = session.query(Match).options(joinedload(Match.home_team),
                                       joinedload(Match.away_team))
for m in matches:
    print m.date, m.home_team, m.away_team
```

`m.home_team` and `m.away_team` will be loaded in the same query as `m` using a `JOIN`.

If you insist on using an explicit `.join()` you'll have to [alias](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.aliased) the `Team` entities (not tested):

```
home = aliased(Team)
away = aliased(Team)
q = session.query(Match.date, home, away).join(home, Match.home_team) \
                                         .join(away, Match.away_team)
for date, home_team, away_team in q:
    print date, home_team, away_team
```

Comment: This is a perfect illustration of how to use it.  I tested your later example and it works well.