# SQLAlchemy alias a joined table in a many-to-many relation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In a legacy database we have, there is a pretty special datastructure where we have **two many-to-many relations joining the same two tables** *companies* to *paymentschedules*.

There is a many-to-many relation using an association table called *companies_paymentschedules*, and a second many-to-many relation using an association table called *companies_comp_paymentschedules*.
Both relations serve different purposes.

companies_paymentschedules stores paymentschedules for which the company has a *discount*, companies_comp_paymentschedules stores paymentschedules that are *linked to the company*.

(I know that this could be simplified by replacing these tables with a single lookup table, but that is not an option in this legacy database.)

The problem is that I need to join both types of companies (discounted and linked) in the same query. SQLAlchemy joins both tables without problems, but it also joins the companies table, and calls them both "companies", which leads to a SQL syntax error (using MSSQL BTW).

This is the query:

```
q = Paymentschedules.query
# join companies if a company is specified
if company is not None:
    q = q.join(Paymentschedules.companies)
    q = q.join(Paymentschedules.companies_with_reduction)
```

The many-to-many relations are both defined in our *companies* model, and look like this:

```
paymentschedules_with_reduction = relationship("Paymentschedules", secondary=companies_paymentschedules, backref="companies_with_reduction")

paymentschedules = relationship("Paymentschedules", secondary=companies_comp_paymentschedules, backref="companies")
```

The problem is that the JOINS trigger SQLAlchemy to create a SQL statement that looks like this:

```
FROM paymentschedules
JOIN companies_comp_paymentschedules AS companies_comp_paymentschedules_1 ON paymentschedules.pmsd_id = companies_comp_paymentschedules_1.pmsd_id
JOIN companies ON companies.comp_id = companies_comp_paymentschedules_1.comp_id
JOIN companies_paymentschedules AS companies_paymentschedules_1 ON paymentschedules.pmsd_id = companies_paymentschedules_1.pmsd_id
JOIN companies ON companies.comp_id = companies_paymentschedules_1.comp_id
```

The two lookup tables have different names, but the related companies table is called "companies" in both cases, causing a SQL error:

```
[SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The objects "companies" and "companies" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them. (1013) (SQLExecDirectW); ...]
```

I have been looking for a way to alias a join, or perhaps alias one of the relations from my lookup-tables to the companies table, but I was unable to do so.

Is there a way to alias a joined many-to-many table?

**update:**

Based on the suggestion by @IljaEverilä I found this: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html?highlight=onclause (see "*Joins to a Target with an ON Clause*") as a method to alias a joined table, but the example only shows how to alias a one-to-many type join. In my case I need to alias the other side of my lookup table, so I can't apply the example code to my situation.

Comment: Can you post the relevant SQL definitions of the two tables, and the desired SQL queries?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35327701/sql-alchemy-join-multiple-columns-from-same-table. In short, you have to alias Companies and join using the `target, onclause` form, where the alias is the target and the relationship the on clause.

Comment: `q = q.join(companies_alias, Paymentschedules.companies)` works. You can pass a relationship as the "onclause", wrt. passing an SQL expression.